# What is difference between C++ and C regex

Tags: regex

What is the difference between usage of regex in C++ and C? 
The below code is C++11 and the answer when I run this code is 
"mismatch", but for the C code it is "match".

Are there any rules or documents which precisely describe this differences?

C++ code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

        const std::regex re("^@hithere");
        std::smatch match;
        std::string str  ("@hithere");
        if(std::regex_match(str, match,re) && match.size()>1)
        {
                printf("match\n");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("mismatch\n");
        }


}
output: mismatch
```

C code:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int reti;
         regex_t regex;

        reti = regcomp(&regex, "^@hithere", REG_EXTENDED);
        if(!reti)
        {
                printf("compile success\n");

        }

        reti = regexec(&regex, "@hithere", 0, NULL, 0);
        if(!reti)
        {
                printf("match\n");
        }
        else
        {

                printf("mis match\n");
        }


}
output:match
```

Comment: They're two different implementations of regular expressions. `<regex.h>` is defined by POSIX (not by ISO C); `<regex>` is defined by ISO C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you do not have any capturing groups in the regex, and you have a check if there is at least one with

```
 && match.size()>1
```

Change it to

```
 && match.size()==1
```

And you will get [expected result](http://ideone.com/uMIqPZ).

See [`std::match_results::size` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/size/):

> **Return number of matches**
>   Returns the number of *matches* and *sub-matches* in the `match_results` object.